# Handsontable creates double headers

Tags: jquery, css, html, handsontable

My handsontable instance has something what looks like double headers: 
 [image]

Within the browser the yellow marked one is the **ColHeader** and is also 
the one that goes down with the scrolling.

I have an Array with Objects. With this structure:

```
    Array[Object,Object,Object...]
```

Each Object has multiple parameters and has 'normal' object structure like:

```
    id: 'value'
    id: 'value'
```

The handsontable instance:

```
    var $container = $("#viewTest");
    $container.handsontable({
          data: sub,
          colHeaders: true
    });
```

**viewTest** is the div container.
**sub** is the name of the array.

Everything looked ok until i tried to add **colHeaders**. I do not whant
to display all the parameters so i only created columns for some, worked also fine. I have now removed everything else and still getting the same issue. I have removed also the **css** styling like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282792/double-rendering-of-col-and-row-headers-using-handsontable).

Maybe one more information: I take the **array** out of a ajax responce. 
I save it in a variable like :

```
    var sub = responce.data[i];
```

I am not aware that that changes anything.

I would appricate a idea where this comes from. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please create a test case (on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for example), which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Yes i tried that but i am also not abel to reproduce the error in jsfiddle there it looks and works like expected ? [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MisterT/zw13mLg3/)  So it seems there is a problem with the object itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the link to the css file had a typo ^^ So the Clone and the ht-master
where out of sync.